# Write a Java program to summarize the data from an input file and output a report

Tags: java, input, switch-statement

I need help writing a Java program to summarize the data from the input file sprocketorders.txt and output a report similar to the one below:

```
                                Spacely Sprockets
                         Taking Sprockets into the Future 
                              Sales Summary Report
            Sprocket Number                          Total Quantity Sold
                 1                                           90
                 2                                           155
                 3                                           50
                 4                                           300
                 5                                           100
```

The data in this chart comes from the .txt file I named above. The info contained in this txt file is as such:

```
 3   50
 2   20
 2   100
 5   15
 1   90
 5   85
 4   300
 2   35
 3   100
```

The report needs to appear in the output window.

I want to use the switch structure. This is the switch structure fragment I have to use as a reference:

```
 switch (snum)
    {
        case 1: part1total = part1total + quantity;
            break;
        case 2: part2total = part2total + quantity;
            break;
        case 3: part3total = part3total + quantity;
            break;
        case 4: part4total = part4total + quantity;
            break;
        case 5: part5total = part5total + quantity;
            break;
        default: System.out.println("Bad sprocket number");

    }
```

This is the code I have so far to establish that it is inputting from a file:

```
 package spacely.sprockets;

 public class SpacelySprockets
 {

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    InputFile orderinfo;
    orderinfo = new InputFile("sprocketorders.txt");

 }
 }
```

How can I use the switch structure summarize the data from the txt file and output the report? It's just not making sense to me how I can get it to input the data from the txt file and have it all displayed like the example below. I really just need some solid direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please try following code:

Please do not forget to change file path

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class FileParsingDemo{

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "D:/vijay/temp.txt"));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // process the line.
                // System.out.println(line);

                line = line.trim();
                String number = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" "));
                String qlty = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(" "));


                int found=0;
                for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {

                    if (map.containsKey(number.trim())) {

                        String oldQlt=map.get(number.trim());



                        int totalqlt=Integer.parseInt(oldQlt) + Integer.parseInt(qlty.trim());


                        map.remove(number.trim());
                        map.put(number, ""+totalqlt);
                        found=1;
                        break;

                    }

                }
                if(found==0)
                {
                    map.put(number.trim(), qlty.trim());

                }


            }
            br.close();

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
                //to get key
              System.out.println(e.getKey() +" ---- " + e.getValue());
                //and to get value

            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and I get a "String index out of range: -1" error when I try to run it.

Comment: in which line?? it run perfectly in my system and give me output as you want. can you shown me code that you have tried with file?

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to :

1, Use a HashhMap and keep Rocket Number as key and Quantity sold as
value.

2.Everytime you read a rocket number from the input file, check if the number already exists in the Map, if yes, get the quantity related
 to the number, add the existing quantity with the quantity read from
 the file and put it back into the map. if the number doesn't exist,
 then add it to the map along wth the quantity.

3.Sort the map in ascending order.

4.Write it back to a new file with some kind of formatting which seems appropriate.

PS : Use FileReader and BufferedReader to read files. FileWriter and BufferdWriter to write files.

Answer (score 0):

Use a buffered reader wrapping a file reader:

```
BufferedReader sprocketFileReader = new BufferedReader(
                                      new FileReader("myFile.txt")
                                    );
```

(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

- Read the file line by line with the BufferedReader's readLine method

  ```
  while ( ( line = sprockFileReader.readLine() ) !=null) {...}
  ```
- Use String.split to separate the number from the value
- Integer.parseInt() to convert the value from String to int
- String.format together with System.out.println to produce the Output you want.

You might also want to have a look at [try with resouces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to learn about correct stream handling.